# AutoLayout error when anchoring a view to main view - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

because they have no common ancestor.  Does the constraint or its anchors reference items in different view hierarchies?

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let myContainer = UIView()
        myContainer.backgroundColor = .purple
        myContainer.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        myContainer.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        myContainer.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        myContainer.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).isActive = true
        myContainer.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).isActive = true
        self.view.addSubview(myContainer)
}
```

### ERROR:

> > 2019-11-06 20:06:17.763701-0600 Testing AutoLayout[42202:4013241] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'Unable to activate constraint with anchors  and  because they have no common ancestor.  Does the constraint or its anchors reference items in different view hierarchies?  That's illegal.'

If I comment the following two lines the error goes away and `myContainer` view shows in the upper-left corner.

```
    //myContainer.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    //myContainer.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
```

Any idea why the error if 'myContainer' is the only thing I have?

Comment: On a side note. Here is a better way to activate constraints https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/uikit/how-to-activate-multiple-auto-layout-constraints-using-activate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add the view before constraints

```
let myContainer = UIView()
self.view.addSubview(myContainer)
myContainer.backgroundColor = .purple
myContainer.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    myContainer.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor),
    myContainer.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
    myContainer.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200),
    myContainer.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200)
])
```

The reason why **width** and **height** constraints pass , is that both of them are added to the *view itself* while **centerX** and **centerY** are added to the parent view.

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot for pointing that out. Will mark it as the right answer as soon as I can.

Comment: Also, thank you for the tip about activating the constraints.

Answer (score 2):

First of all you should **add views** (one or more views) before **adding constraints.**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
let myContainer = UIView()
self.view.addSubview(myContainer)
myContainer.backgroundColor = .ColorName
myContainer.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
addViewConstraints()
}

func addViewConstraints () {
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    myContainer.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor),
    myContainer.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
    myContainer.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200),
    myContainer.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200)
])
}
```